# Wait until two Observables are complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, fork-join

I want to call a method after two Observables have returned values. I did some searching and it seems like `forkJoin` is what I want, but I can't get it to work. I know both of these Observables are returning values, as I am using the data for each individually elsewhere in the component, so clearly I'm doing something else wrong.

Here is what I tried. I'm using rxjs v6.4.

```
forkJoin(
  this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.getAppointmentsLoading)),
  this.clientStore.pipe(select(fromClientStore.getClientsLoading)),
).subscribe(
  ([res1, res2]) => {
    console.log('res1', res1);
    console.log('res2', res2);
  },
  err => console.error(err),
);
```

Nothing is logging to the console and I am not getting any errors. Again, the Observables I am passing in are definitely returning values.

Am I doing something wrong, or am I taking the wrong approach entirely by using `forkJoin`?

Comment: [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) waits until all of the sources *complete*, does that ever happen? Maybe try `combineLatest` or `zip` to see if they emit without completing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits when all the observables complete (or when one of them throws an error), not when they emit.

You can use `combineLatest` instead.

Be careful to **not** import the instance operator from `'rxjs/operators'`. It's a common mistake caused by some IDEs auto-import feature. In this case, we need the static version, imported from `'rxjs'`:

```js
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs';

combineLatest([
  this.store.pipe(select(fromStore.getAppointmentsLoading)),
  this.clientStore.pipe(select(fromClientStore.getClientsLoading)),
]).subscribe(
  ([res1, res2]) => {
    console.log('res1', res1);
    console.log('res2', res2);
  },
  err => console.error(err),
);
```

Comment: How can I do the same but also call a method when both observables are completed?

Comment: Dude the problem with combineLatest is it combines null value also through which we initialize a behaviorSubject observable.

Comment: Add `skip(1)` to the `BehaviorSubject` to ignore the first emission.